# Assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Very new to ember and trying to mess around with my first test script. I keep getting the error in the title and it occurs when I try to use handlebars to loop through a data fixture. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devpixel/7ubQz/12/)

Loop statement that is giving error

```
{{#each player in controller}}
<tr> <!-- foreach statement here order by wins>loss>ties -->
 <td>{{ name }}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

App.JS

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
});
// Router
App.Router.map(function(){});

App.PlayersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Player.find();
    }
});
// Controllers
App.PlayersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
// View Helpers
// Models
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Player = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    wins: DS.attr('number'),
    losses: DS.attr('number'),
    ties: DS.attr('number'),
    drop: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Player.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Joe Jame',
    wins: 2,
    losses: 0,
    ties: 0,
    drop: 'False'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Froggy Bottom',
    wins: 2,
    losses: 0,
    ties: 0,
    drop: 'False'
}];
```

Comment: without seeing any code there will be not much help, how does your script looks like?

Comment: Sorry about that, hit submit too quickly, just posted link to fiddle plus some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more answer, first I've ported your example to jsbin IMO it's more reliable than jsfiddle, for the kind of setup you have I've changed the `render` statement to `partial` and renamed the `playerlist` template to `_playerlist`. additionally I've defined in the `IndexRoute` a `model` hook to get your fixture data, and this are the results: http://jsbin.com/iceraz/2/edit. It seams to be working now as expected. Since we are using the `partial` helper there is no need for an extra `Playerlist` controller nor route, it will be all handled in the `IndexRoute`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [`render` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render) creates a new template/view/controller so in your case you will need to pass in the array of `Player` objects to allow the `playerlist` template to have the correct context for rendering.

```
{{ render "playerlist" content }}
```

You also need to change `PlayersRoute` to `IndexRoute` otherwise the `model` hook won't get called and your data won't be loaded.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Player.find();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/devpixel/7ubQz/12/)